# How to send email to users located anywhere in world from Lambdas deployed in AWS CHINA region

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, aws-sam

I am working on a project which needs to be extended and deployed to China with tech stack of JS. All of the backend APIs are AWS serverless lambdas which would be deployed to another AWS account specific for China. We are using SES for sending emails to users but we are not sure how would emails be send to users located anywhere in the world from lambdas deployed to china region since SES is not available in China.

Does anybody knows of the ways email be send from lambdas located in AWS china region? I know SNS can send emails but it cannot attach files thus SNS cannot be an option.

Is there any other AWS service that we can leverage or do we have to spin up our own SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a cross-region call.

Since you data is going to cross the China to send email anywhere that should be fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).